# Arrays in C that adds pairs and compares to find the max

Tags: c, arrays, math, addition

So I have a problem writing a code.

I'm just starting out in the programming world, I need to create an array that contains between 2 to 20 integers, and then add the first and last integer together to get a Max value; for example in this [23; 12; 78; 52; 76; 15; 21; 82; 64; 91], the program adds 23 + 91, then 12 + 62, then 78 + 82, and then after that prints out the max sum, and it'll only work if there is an even number of arrays input, if odd it won't work.

Please what would the code be like?

This is a bit of the code I've been able to write so far

```
int m, a[20], sum, K, temp;
printf("Enter size of array:\n");
scanf_s("%d", &m);

if (m > 20 || m < 2 || m % 2 != 0)
{
    error_printf("Invalid input data");
    WAIT_ANY_KEY
    return 0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    printf("Enter Number [%d] : ", i + 1);
    scanf_s("%d", &a[i]);
    if (a[i] > 1000 || a[i] < 0)
        {
            error_printf("Invalid Input data");
            WAIT_ANY_KEY
                return 0;
        }
    }

    printf("\n The largest sum of pairs is : [%d]\n\n", max);
    return 0;
}
```

I'll appreciate if anyone could explain, how instead of having 10 fixed integers to input, I can just input how many digits I want in the array, and also how to fix the sum and find the max.

Thanks

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, I think we should give the guy a chance... he's just starting... rather than to block his question, direct him on the right way to ask...

Comment: @SouravGhosh, I've edited and added a portion of the code

Comment: @Enterprevic, find a way to contact me, and I'll help you...  :P

Comment: @mlwn I've sent an email to you, thanks )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a working example :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int printMatrix ( const char *d, int mtp[], int n ) {
  printf ( "\n The matrix [ %s ] is : ", d );
  for ( int i=0; i<n-1; i++ ) {
    printf ( "%d - ", mtp[i] );
  }
  printf ( "%d", mtp[n-1] );
  return 0;
}

int main () {
  const int N = 20;
  int max=0;
  int n=0;

  while ( n == 0 ) {
    printf ( " Number of Items should be even, between 2 and 20\n" );
    printf ( " Enter the number of items : " );
    scanf  ( "%d", &n );
    if ( n>20 || n%2 != 0 || n<2 ) n = 0;
  }

  int M[N] = {0};
  int mM[int(N/2)] = {0};

  for ( int i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
    printf ( "Enter Number [%d] : ", i+1 );
    scanf  ( "%d", &M[i] );
  }

  for ( int i=0; i<n/2; i++ ) {
    mM[i] = M[i] + M[n-1-i];
  }

  for ( int i=0; i<n/2; i++) {
    if (mM[i] > max) max = mM[i];
  }

  printMatrix ( "Starting   ", M, n );
  printMatrix ( "Couples Sum", mM, n/2 );
  printf ( "\n The max is : [%d]\n\n", max );
  return 0;
}
```